# Html Canvas draw line using dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to upload image based on that How to draw a line between selected dots and i want to capture that particular image
so please suggest how to write in html5

Comment: Show your code effort.

Comment: stackoverflow not a code generator XD

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a path, giving certain points (or dots) on the canvas to draw a line between. Then you can stroke the line (actually draw the line to the canvas).

```
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("CANVAS")), context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.beginPath();
  // all points are given as x (from left to right), y (from top to bottom)
  context.moveTo(10, 20); // x = 10 (10 px from the left edge of the canvas), y = 20 (20 px from the top edge of the canvas)
  context.lineTo(100, 97); // x = 100, y = 97
  context.lineTo(50, 105); // x = 50, y = 100

context.stroke();
```

[[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Drawing_paths)]

Comment: I want to draw line dynamically .

Comment: Okay. So you can use variables and loops and so on to say where each point is.

Comment: can you send me sample code for creating rectangle based on dots

Comment: Check out that MDN page I linked you to. It explains how to do anything you like with canvas paths.

There is `rect` to plot a rectangle (or square) before stroking with a line or filling with a colour, or `fillRect` or `strokeRect` to do all that in one go. Or you can just use values that would make up the 4 corners of a rectangle using that `lineTo`.

The MDN page is really very helpful, so I'd recommend looking at that and see how you go. If you still have troubles after you've read through the relevant parts of that page, you can ask me again. I'd be happy to help.

Comment: I completed to add to dots but i need to exit a path if first dot and last dot is same

Comment: Could you do an if statement to change that? When you get to the last point, you could compare it against the first dot. If they are the different, add it to the path. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: Or you could just add it to the path anyway. It'll work just fine, I think.